# Modify array to have single quotes around value

Tags: php, arrays

How would I modify an array in php from:

```
$colors = [red, green, blue]
```

To having single quotes around each value:

```
$colors = 'red', 'green', 'blue'
```

Comment: `$colors  = "'" . implode("', '", $colors) . "'";`

Comment: you will propably run into a notic because you are using undefined constants.

Comment: @Dwza I can change the source of the array. Do you recommend that I add keys to the values?

Comment: you dont need to :) just type **$colors = ["red","green","blue"];** btw, whats the reason why you want to have a string formated like first comment?

Comment: @Dwza I'm trying to put the array into a mysql query that will search my database for matches something like `SELECT `ref_id` FROM `main` WHERE `ref_id` IN ($colors)`

Comment: yes, guess thats to only way how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something on the lines of `$colors = "'" . implode("', '", $colors) . "'";` would help you out in this situation.

Comment: nice copy of the comment what was given!